# Introductions to classical and nonclassical logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I've found [Eric Schechter: Classical and Nonclassical Logics: An Introduction to the Mathematics of Propositions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691122792) a really nice book. But I'd like to skim through other books about the same subject, at the moment, I've been able to find only these ones:

- [An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic: From If to Is.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521670268)
- [Logical Options: An Introduction to Classical and Alternative Logics.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1551112973)

Can you suggest me more introductory books to classical and nonclassical logics?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837607/book-about-different-kind-of-logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merrie Bergmann's [An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521707579) covers first-order classical, three-valued, and fuzzy logic (including sections on quantification theory in classical, three-valued, and fuzzy logic).

A classic textbook on many-valued logic is Rosser and Turquette's [Many-valued Logics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BVSDQO).

Gottwald has [A Treatise on Many-Valued Logics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0863802621).

Richard L. Epstein's book [Propositional Logics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/053455847X)seems similar to Schecter's in that many different kinds of propositional logics get covered.

You might also want to look at papers... in the volume [Polish Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198243049) I know there's a few papers by Wajsberg one on three-valued logic, and another which all sorts of different axiom sets for the implicational calculus of propositions.

I also highly recommend A. N. Prior's [Formal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198241569) (2nd edition) which has a highly useful and still rather comprehensive appendix of different axiom sets for logical calculi.
The 2nd appendix in the 2nd edition also contains a proof that tells you about lots of classical implicational calculi.

Additionally, you might want to see Ted Ulrich's [pages](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/index.html) which cover different axiom sets (almost entirely single axioms, but multiple axiom sets also get discussed) for a few logical calculi.